# Declare array of bsonType in mongoDb schema

Tags: json, mongodb, realm, bson

How to declare an array of different types in mongoDb schemas?

I have a value in a document which can be a double or an int and I tried declaring it like this:

```
"numberOf": {
                "bsonType": ["long", "int"]
              },
```

And I received that error:

> property "numberOf" has invalid type: type [long,int] is not supported

In the [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/document-schemas/#general) they say that you can declare an array of bsonTypes or types like that:

```
"type": "<JSON Type>" | ["<JSON Type>", ...],
"bsonType": "<BSON Type>" | ["<BSON Type>", ...],
```

I also tried:

```
"numberOf": {
                "type": "number"
              },
```

And I can't save my schema getting this:

[image: error processing request]

I don't know what I missed.

Comment: I don't know what this - `["long", "int"]` is. If you want to define multiple types, use `"bsonType": "int" | "long" | "double" | "decimal",`

Comment: I tried it and it doesn’t work

Comment: "It doesn't work" is pretty vague. Can you clarify what you tried and what isn't working? Please update the question with details.

Comment: I just want to have multiple bsonTypes on my properties. Should be pretty easy.
For example "numberOf" could be an int or a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem would come from Sync [see here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/realm-schema-for-different-object-types-in-array/102497/9).
They working on it.

Right now, it is not possible to sync multiple types of data for a single field.

What I did is I changed my types to "mixed":

```
"numberOf": {
                "bsonType": "mixed"
              },
```

This feature is in beta ([see here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/react-native/data-types/mixed/)) and, probably, you'll have to update your Realm package.

Just do in your terminal

```
npm install realm
```

Then

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Be careful of breaking changes.

If needed, uninstall your application on your emulator/simulator then

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

or

```
npx react-native run-android
```